# Mysql query small fix

Tags: mysql

I need please some help with this query, **i am not expert with mysql, so i am just learning**

I am just doing some lessons on sql, so i was reading the manual but, i just don't know how to get it correct...

*what I have tried*

1 - I have used the ' * ' in the sub query but it seems to be not working
2 - should I replace the = with in - but what dose ( in ) mean
3 - or should you remove the parenthesis from sub query .

the mysql manual is driving me crazy probably because I am beginner.

what is wrong with the following query:

```
select * from order where orderid = (select orderId from orderItems where itemQty > 50)
```

Comment: What indication do you have that something is wrong with it?

Comment: actually when i run it, it returns an empty results...

Answer (score 1):

ORDER is a mysql reserved word. escape it with ticks: `order`

Reserved word list here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Also, you are returning a set in your subquery. You may want to limit it to 1 or do as Rahul suggests and use IN operator instead of = to return a group

```
select * from `order` 
where orderid = (
    select orderId 
    from orderItems 
    where itemQty > 50 
    ORDER_BY orderId 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
select * from `order` where orderid in (select orderId from orderItems where itemQty > 50)
```

`ORDER` is a mysql reserved word. Also I would suggest you to use `IN` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

Use `in`.

```
select * from order where orderid in (select orderId from orderItems where itemQty > 50)
```

This says, if orderid is in the result of subquery, then true.